# Math functions in Logstash

Tags: logstash

I am looking forward to use mathematical operations on the input received in Logstash, but unable to see any of such **filter**.

**Input is as following:**

```
{
  "user_id": "User123",
  "date": "2016 Jun 26 12:00:12",
  "data": {
    "doc_name": "mydocs.xls",
    "doc_size": "8526587",
  }
}
```

**The "doc_size" field will have bytes, I would like to add a new field say "doc_size_mb" which will contain the size in MB's.**

So I want a simple division operation here like:

doc_size_mb = doc_size/(1024*1024)

I could see a [link](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/logstash-filter-math/0.2/LogStash/Filters/Math) which says Logstash has math filter, but this is not visible [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html) .

Comment: Alternatively, if you use Kibana for visualising your data, it supports scripted fields that can do your math.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `logstash-filter-math` is not a core plugin but it is available [here](https://github.com/robin13/logstash-filter-math). You can follow the next steps in order or install it:

```
> git clone https://github.com/robin13/logstash-filter-math.git
> cd logstash-filter-math
> gem build
> $LS_HOME/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-math-0.2.gem
```

If you don't want to install a 3rd party plugin just for that, you can also easily achieve the same computation with a [`ruby` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html):

```
filter {
   ruby {
      code => "event['data']['doc_size_mb'] = event['data']['doc_size'].to_i / (1024 * 1024)"
   }
}
```

Comment: run "gem build logstash-filter-math.gemspec" if you run into an error.

Answer (score 4):

I tried using the above approach to multiply an **existing field** by a factor value and update the value of the existing field in the event by this new scaled value in Logstash 7.0.1, but it did not work as expected. 
I modified it to use the Event API's `set()` and `get()` methods which worked out for me.

Initial approach (did not work) -

```
filter {
     ruby {
        code => "event['data']['myField'] = event['data']['myField'].to_i * 0.25"
          }
       }
```

Working solution -

```
filter {
     ruby {
        code => "event.set('myField',event.get('myField')* 0.25)
          }
       }
```

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html - "Prior to version 5.0, developers could access and manipulate event data by directly using Ruby hash syntax." Seems one must use `.set` and `.get` now. Also works with nested fields, but be careful with your quotes. Example: `ruby { code => "event.set('[memory][used]', event.get('[memory][total]') - event.get('[memory][free]'))" }`

Comment: Pls update the working solution as it has issues.
filter {
        ruby {
            code => "event.set('myField',event.get('myField').to_i * 0.25)"
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

The math filter or ruby are options for the general case of doing math in logstash, but for this specific use-case (converting MB) there is the [bytes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-bytes.html) filter.