# Elasticsearch + Logstash: How to add a fields based on existing data at importing time

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Currently, I'm importing data into Elastic through logstash, at this time by reading csv files.

Now let's say I have two numeric fields in the csv, age, and weight.
I would need to add a 3rd field on the fly, by making a math on the age, the weight and another external data ( or function result ); and I need that 3rd field to be created when importing the data.

There is any way to do this? 
What could be the best practice?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all Logstash filter sections, you can add fields via `add_field`, but that's typically static data.

[Math calculations need a separate plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38070513/2308683)

As mentioned there, the ruby filter plugin would probably be your best option. Here is an example snippet for your pipeline

```
filter {

     # add calculated field, for example BMI, from height and weight 
    ruby {
        code => "event['data']['bmi'] = event['data']['weight'].to_i / (event['data']['height'].to_i)"
   }
}
```

Alternatively, in Kibana, there are [Scripted fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html) meant to be visualized, but cannot be queried

Comment: "Logstash variable scope" means variables declared in the logstash config?

Comment: No. Like when you parse data in logstash, you can reference it by `%{var}`. Somewhere (e.g. a previous filter stage) you need to add/create the `var` field variable before it can be referenced

Comment: Be careful, the new syntax for `ruby` in Logstash has changed from `event['field']` to `event.get('field')`